# Identifying a beetle from northern California

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Just found this organism crawling across my wall on the second story at around 12:30 AM. We're in Sonoma County in California. Our best guess so far is a soldier beetle, but the coloration doesn't seem to match any images we can find online. It's body was about 1.5 inches long and was a uniform brownish-tan color with black eyes. It may be worth noting we're in the middle of the worst heat wave we've seen in 15 years of living here.

[image: photo of the insect, looks like a tan beetle with a long, straight body and long antennae]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a long-horned beetle, family **Cerambycidae**; the site http://www.sbcollections.org/cbp/DB_Query.aspx?Field=family&Value=Cerambycidae has a list of California species, with links to pages on each species (there are 387; not all species pages feature illustrations -- those that do figure museum specimens).  From that list the first that resembled your photograph is that covering *Centrodera spurca* (LeConte 1856), which has been found in Sonoma County; given that I haven't gone through the entire list there are likely other possibilities.

***Centrodera spurca***

[image]

Comment: I agree it's a long-horned beetle (so +1) but a picture to compare it to would be helpful. I edited to add. Not sure if it's the same beetle, though. They look like they can easily be mistaken within the group.